# Show that group of matrices is not a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-groups

This example is from Tapp's book "Matrix Groups for Undergraduates":

[image]

I'm trying to show that $G$ does not have the structure of a manifold, and thus cannot be a Lie group.

Any neighborhood of $I$ contains matrices of the form $g_{2\pi n}$ for arbitrarily large $n$. My idea is to try to show that this means that $I$ does not have a neighborhood diffeomorphic to a subset of the Euclidean space, but I cannot seem to make the argument work. Thanks!

Comment: For this, you need his exact definition of "matrix group."

Comment: @Randall: Curious—is it an unusual definition?

Comment: No, it's just rigged up so that a student can prove the usual theorems in Lie theory with matrix groups and not fully-abstract Lie groups.

Comment: You could check whether or not this subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb C)$ is closed and then...

Comment: The point is that $G$ is not closed in $GL_2(\mathbb C)$. Indeed, $G$ can be identified with the subspace $(1,t)\mathbb R\subset\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$, which is dense.

Comment: It is of course a manifold (diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$), but not a submanifold of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ under the canonical embedding.